# CSS styles not displaying properly (firebase)

Tags: css, reactjs, firebase, mern

I deployed a SPA in Firebase and the CSS styles only look good when I refresh the browser. Here is short video to show the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIuQ-axizj8

My firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems that the issue is only related with background image since the rest of the application has the correct styles. Here is my website so you can verify the problem: https://ligafiferos.web.app/61159918604c7700164465bd/players

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console ? Like CSS not found or something

Comment: No, I only have this issue: A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. In a future version of Chrome, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `background: white;` on `.card` (defined in `Card.css`), use `background-color: white` (which is what you want to change).

Changing the shortcut property `background` changes all `background-*` properties (including `background-image`, which is set to `initial`), and then you depend on the order of CSS loading to have it show the background or not (which may be dependent on many things).

[image: CSS on browser dev console]

If Card.css gets loaded (for some reason) after `PlayItem.css`, then it'll cancel the `.elche-item__content` property `background-image` and replace it with `initial`

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! This worked for me! :)

Comment: @doubting if this was an ok solution, don't forget to mark it as a solution for others to see

Comment: hecho, shur. Gracias y buen floro.